# How to don't save code in vim

Tags: vim, save, folding

is it possible to add text to a file, and make vim don't save it ?

To clarify the thing, I'm creating a vim-plugin that would add perfs informations
above functions, but I don't want these to be saved.

I thought to "fold" these informations, but it's also saved; I searched on Google but it seems nobody ever tried to don't save a part of his code (as it's a bit nonsense :D).

So if you ever heard of such thing, I would grately appreciate it !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may consider to show it in different buffer?

Comment: I'm actually trying to write these informations in every files buffered, and make another buffer would result in a lack of readability.. Is it possible to display a buffer's content in another one ?

Answer (score 7):

Remember that Vim is a *text editor*; your feature is closely related to IDEs. Therefore, I can think of only kludges and hacks:

- The only built-in features that make text appear different that what it is are *conceal*, which can only hide characters or replace them with a single char (not useful for you), and *folding*, where you could use a custom `'foldtext'` to add your information (but it would interfere with the regular filetype's folding).
- In GVIM, you could use a mouse tooltip through the `'balloonexpr'`.
- You could actually modify the text on `BufWritePre` / `BufWritePost` events, but if the information is only supplementary and should never be persisted, that's unnatural (jumps, searches, etc. would also be affected), and it could break, leaving the text behind.
- Many plugins create a separate *scratch buffer* with `:new` and `:setlocal buftype=nofile`; see `:help special-buffers`. In that, you can do whatever you want, but it's separate from the original file.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll gather these informations and try to make this plugin differently. I was aware that this could maybe be impossible..